# how to make datetimepicker select specific day in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm doing a program for Doctor Clinics , and you know that is each doctor have specific clinic day so how can I make the datetimepicker Enable only one day in all the interval time, for example Sunday only is available and other days are unavailable  ??

Comment: Please see the guidelines for posting a question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: windows Form actually ..

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the range (in your case one day) by setting the MinDate and MaxDate properties. Although I don't understand why you allow the user to pick from the dropdown if you already know there is only one day to select from...you should just default the control to the specific clinic day and disable the control. Either way this is an example to set the dropdown date selection range to 5 days:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful

`<DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="3/1/2010" End="3/7/2010"/>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="3/8/2010" End="3/8/2010"/>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="3/15/2010" End="3/15/2010"/>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="3/22/2010" End="3/22/2010"/>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="3/29/2010" End="3/29/2010"/>
</DatePicker.BlackoutDates>`

[Reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-datepicker/)

Comment: This will work for WPF although the OP mentioned WinForms.